# How do I copy a .o file from one directory to another in Mac terminal?

Tags: linux, macos

For my programming class my professor gave us a file we can use in our homework he's already written but it's in his directory for the class and I need to put it in my directory I've created for the homework with all the files I've written on my own. I've tried using the CP command but it tells me the destination directory doesn't exist. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you confirmed the destination directory actually exists? Or if there's an error in your command?

Comment: no it exists. In the class we use wilily to be able to submit everything. All the files he gives us are in a directory the whole class can access but we have to create our own directories for the files we write. So he keeps his files in a directory called "~ee160" and ours are in a directory called "ee160"

Comment: If the destination folder exists and you have permissions you should be able to do what you want. However, the error message suggests otherwise - and also not a permissions problem - so it must be your command what's wrong. Fell free to [edit] the question to provide more information.